# Why the run time is shorter when I use a lock in a c++ program?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, runtime

I am practise the multithreaded programming with cpp. And when I use the `std::lock_guard` in the same code, its run time becomes shorter than before. That's amazing, why?
The lock version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


class test {
    std::mutex m;
    int a;
public:
    test() :a(0) {}
    void add() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
            a++;
        }
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    test t;
    auto start = clock();
    std::thread t1(&test::add, ref(t));
    std::thread t2(&test::add, ref(t));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    auto end = clock();

    t.print();

    cout << "time = " << double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the ouput is:

```
2000000000
time = 5.71852s
```

the no lock version is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


class test {
    std::mutex m;
    int a;
public:
    test() :a(0) {}
    void add() {
        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
            a++;
        }
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    test t;
    auto start = clock();
    std::thread t1(&test::add, ref(t));
    std::thread t2(&test::add, ref(t));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    auto end = clock();

    t.print();

    cout << "time = " << double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
1010269798
time = 10.765s
```

I'm using the ubuntu1804, g++ version is :

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

In my opinion, the lock is an extra operation, it should cost more time of course.

Maybe someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce on my system. When using the lock you get a sequential execution. Without the lock the threads access `a` in parallel. Besides the risk of generating wrong results (which your code does) there can also be some unexpected cache system behavior. I can't be sure about that but if you have access to cache hit/miss information I would check that.

Comment: I can understand reason of the wrong result. But I'm curious about the run time difference between two versions.

Comment: As I said... depending on the implementation of the cache system (and processor in general) there could be much more cache miss and evictions when you let two threads access the same variable in parallel. Something that may slow things down significantly. As I can't reproduce your results on my server, I can't check it. You need to check it on your system. Anyway... it's just an idea. Maybe I'm all wrong ;-)

Comment: Fine, I got what you mean, and hit/miss rate sounds reasonable. Thanks♪(･ω･)ﾉ

Comment: You may find this interresting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing It's not exactly the same as your case (as your threads do share the same variable). However, the effect on the cache system is likely the same. To find out you need to dig real deep into the low level implementation of your processor.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a variable from multiple threads cause an **undefined behaviour**. This means the compiler ans the processor are free to do whatever they want in this case (like removing the loop for example, or not reloading the variable from memory since it is not supposed to be modified by another thread in the first place). As a result, studying performance of this case is not really relevant.

Assuming the compiler do not perform any (allowed) advanced optimizations, the program should contain a **race condition**. It is certainly slower because of a **cache-line bouncing** effect: multiple cores compete for the same locked cache-line and moving it from one core to another is very slow compared to increasing the variable from the L1 cache (this is certainly the overhead you see). Indeed, on standard x86-64 platforms like mainstream Intel processors, moving a locked cache line from one core to another means invalidating copies of the cache line of other L1/L2 cores and fetching it from the L3 cache which is much slower than the L1 (lower throughput & much higher latency). Note that this behaviour is **dependent of the target platform** (mainly the processor, besides compiler optimizations), but most platforms work similarly. For more information please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherency_protocols_(examples)) about **cache-coherence protocols**.